# Javascript Getting specific element (of parent) by name

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyname

I'm using custom tags to define sections in an application, so I have something like this:

```
<mysection>

   <form>
       <input name="myfield">
   </form>

</mysection>
```

I'm using the following and able to get the tag (printed to console, everything is groovy)

```
var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('mysection');
```

The issue I'm having is finding the child field by name:

```
var myfield = parent.getElementsByName("myfield");
```

...as I don't want to pick up on any other 'sections' that might have an input with the name 'myfield'.

**EDIT:**

```
var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('mysection')[0];
```

was suggested and returns to console the section contents, however, `getElementsByName` throws an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'getElementsByName'
```

Comment: By using the id you can get rid of all your problems.

Comment: Because this is a large project and I don't want ID overload.

Comment: Then you should also read this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575671/on-ie-document-getelementsbyname-wont-work/14575673#14575673

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `getElementsByTagName()` and `getElementsByName()` will return a NodeList, you need to get the first element of the list like this:

```
var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('mysection')[0];
var myfield = parent.getElementsByName("myfield")[0];
```

**Edit**

You were correct, `getElementsByName` is not valid for an element. I am unsure how to localize the functionality of it as you are trying to do. It seems that it will only work for `document`. You may have to write your own implementation of `getElementsByName` if you want to use it in a localized scope.

**Second Edit**

To be nice, I made that implementation for you :D Here it is in all its "glory".

```
Element.prototype.getElementsByName = function (arg) {
    var returnList = [];
    (function BuildReturn(startPoint) {
        for (var child in startPoint) {
            if (startPoint[child].nodeType != 1) continue; //not an element
            if (startPoint[child].getAttribute("name") == arg) returnList.push(startPoint[child]);
            if (startPoint[child].childNodes.length > 0) {
                BuildReturn(startPoint[child].childNodes);
            }
        }
    })(this.childNodes);
    return returnList;
};
var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('mysection')[0];
var myfield = parent.getElementsByName("myfield")[0];
```

**Small fix**

I was incorrectly passing the element and not its children into the recursion. The code above has been edited with the proper argument passed now. See working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/js6NP/5/

Comment: Note: `getElementsByTagName()` and `getElementsByName()` do not return an `Array`. Instead, they return a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList).

Comment: @Derek - Not technically, made the change to reflect that it is a NodeList and not an array.

Comment: `getElementsByName` has been returning the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'getElementsByName'`

Comment: @TravisJ - while it looks good, I'm getting 'Cannot read nodeType of null' - http://jsfiddle.net/fluidbyte/js6NP/1/

Comment: @Fluidbyte - Thank you for point that out, I was using `BuildReturn(startPoint[child]);` on accident, that line should have read: `BuildReturn(startPoint[child].childNodes);`. I edited the fix in the answer along with a working jsfiddle.

Comment: Thank you for all your work, however, I found a method 'querySelectorAll' that is much more efficient. I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 9):

I actually found a much more simple way to handle this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('mysection [name="myfield"]');
```

Here you can see an example where it only modifies the field inside the section specified: http://jsfiddle.net/fluidbyte/kph6H/

qSA supports modern browsers and is compatible down to IE8, Here's a polyfill to support back to IE7: https://gist.github.com/2724353

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByName` won't work on a DOM element reference. Use `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll` instead. In example:

```
var parent  = document.getElementsByTagName('mysection')[0];
var myfield = parent.querySelector("[name='myfield']");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use an ID instead:

```
<mysection>
    <form>
         <input name="myfield" id="fieldName">
    </form>
</mysection>
```

```
var myfield = document.getElementById("fieldName");
```

ID's are [supposed to be unique on a page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2). So you shouldn't have trouble accessing the right element.

If you really ***have*** to use name/tagname, `getElementsByTagName` and `getElementsByName` both always return a `array` (A empty one if no element was found). you can access the right element, just like you'd access elements in arrays:
`document.getElementsByTagName('mysection')[0];` For the first element with tagname `mysection`.