# On IE document.getElementsByName won't work

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, getelementsbyname

I use this code:

```
<div name="1234">
   <img src="pic.gif" height="70" width="100" onMouseOver="clear('1234')">
</div>
```

And:

```
function clear(element_name){
    document.getElementsByName(element_name)[0].innerHTML="";
}
```

It does work in Firefox and Opera, but doesn't work in IE 6.0 or IE 8.0, and probably not even in newer IE's.

What to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the problem is this: IE understands document.getElementsByName(...)[0] as document.getElementById(...). So if you would define also an id for your element, the method document.getElementsByName(element_name)[0].innerHTML="" will surprisingly also work in IE!

But since you anyway need to define an id due to IE, and since an id must always start with a char first, you must use:

```
<div id="a234">
    <img src="pic.gif" height="70" width="100" onMouseOver="clear('a234')">
</div>
```

And this command:

```
function clear(element_id){
    document.getElementById(element_id).innerHTML="";
}
```

Even more, document.getElementsByName(...)[0] is slower in Firefox: http://www.uize.com/tests/performance/getElementById-vs-getElementsByName.html

So the id definitely wins the race.

**UPDATE:**

Also important is the fact, that we can adress every id by #a234{...} in a **CSS** file. So we can define *an own style for every id*, and this makes the id even more powerful.

Comment: Worth pointing out that an ID isn't allowed to start with a number.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks. More details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247840/what-are-legal-characters-for-an-html-element-id

Answer (score 2):

Using **getElementsByName** to get a DOM Element where the **name** attribute is not part of the W3C spec (eg, in the question, name doesn't exist for DIV element), IE doesn't get those elements. FF does it. 

Just to clarify: ***expando attribute*** or better known as ***custom attribute*** is what I am talking about attributes that are not part of the W3C spec.

Read: [getElementsByName in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278719/getelementsbyname-in-ie7) 
Read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536438(VS.85).aspx

So in conclusion:
Use **getElementsByName** when trying to get **"Form Controls"** (input, select, textarea) because they have **name** as an attribute according to the spec.

If the elements are not Form Controls, use getElementById instead.