# Im unable to get click button on VBA script to work. Any advice?

Tags: vba, forms, button, submit, fill

Im automating a form with excel to autofill and submit. I am able to fill my form but I can't get the submit button to work. I've tried about 50 different types of code and I cant get it to work. Could you guys help me figure out how to get it to submit?

This is the HTML code for the button

field HTML properties Below

```
<input type="button" value="submit" class="button" onclick="submitIt()">
```

Here are 2 that I though would work but didnt

1st-- this one works but it gives me an error on the page which is weird. basically the error comes back as an incorrect company. but if i comment it out and fill the form and manually click the button it submits just fine.

```
IE.document.getElementsByClassName("button")(0).Click
```

2nd - I thought this worked at one point but i cant seem to get it to work now.

```
Set doc = IE.document
Set div = IE.document.getElementByClassnName("button")
div.FireEvent "submitIt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is a pretty common question.

Try:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="mybutton">
```

and then

```
With IE.document

    Set elems = .getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each e In elems

        If (e.getAttribute("value") = "mybutton") Then
            e.Click
            Exit For
        End If

    Next e

End With
```

More examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28159691/8112776), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27549647/click-a-websites-button-with-excel-vba), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17181611/8112776), [etc](https://www.google.ca/search?q=click%20button%20on%20web%20page%20with%20vba%20internet%20explorer)...

Here are some [helpful tips](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to consider when posting questions.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the help and the links. I will test them out.