# Web Form Filliable with MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am looking to fill some online form at the work. Currently i have this code but my question is how do i get the Data from the table to the web form.

```
Sub ninja()


Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

ie.Visible = True

ie.Navigate "https://www.google.com/"

         While ie.Busy
            DoEvents
         Wend
' ESte Codigo abajo sirve para escribir en los blanco

ie.Document.getElementById("txtUserId").Value = Form![Alien]<---- Here

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

MS Access is vba, so any vba-code to fill online form should be easy to modify to your needs:

[VBA to Enter Data Online and Submit Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409613/vba-to-enter-data-online-and-submit-form)