# IE 8 is not triggering click on input elements type button

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, click, getelementsbyname

The following JavaScript works on Chrome, FF, etc. - it triggers the corresponding button - but not on IE8:

`<input type="submit" value="save" name="save" class="button">`

`document.getElementsByName('save').item(0).click()`

Is there an equivalent (native Javascript) to this which works on IE8?

Comment: Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/627qJ/). It works quite fine here in IE8

Answer (score 0):

Give your form and button an `id`, set the button as type `button`, it should work on every (ancient) browser:

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function alertMsg()   {
 if (confirm("Are you sure you want to submit the form?"))  {
 //Try to submit the form
 document.getElementById('form1').submit();
 }
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="">
<input type="button" onclick="alertMsg()" value="Save" name="action_saveandcontinue" class="button" id="action_saveandcontinue"/>
</form>
```

EDIT: If you have no control over the HTML code, better read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575671/on-ie-document-getelementsbyname-wont-work), [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278719/getelementsbyname-in-ie7) and this MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536438%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: In this case I don't have any influence on the html code. The site is embedded in my site (same origin - so no cross-domain issue) via an iframe. Also the form has more than one input button. On top of that the html elements have no ids.